# Parsing XML data with xml.etree.elementtree and then summing

Tags: python, xml

I am attempting to take the provided sample data, count all the occurrences of 'count', and then add the integers in those locations.

sample xml data: http://python-data.dr-chuck.net/comments_42.xml

My code so far:

```
import urllib
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

url = 'http://python-data.dr-chuck.net/comments_42.xml'
print 'Retrieving', url

site = urllib.urlopen(url)
data = site.read()
print 'Retrieved',len(data),'characters'
print data
tree = ET.fromstring(data)


results = tree.findall('count')
print results

total = results.sum
print total
```

When I run this I get:
printed xml sample web data and then an empty []

My desired output is something like

Retrieved 4204 characters
Count: 50
Sum: 2482

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few issues with your code:

First of all - you need to use correct xpath for elements you're looking for:

```
results = tree.findall('comments/comment/count')
```

This yields:

```
[<Element 'count' at 0x10b42ca10>, <Element 'count' at 0x10b42cad0>, ...]
```

As you can see, they are `Element` instances. Secondly, you have to retrieve tag content from these instances and convert values to integers:

```
counts = [int(r.text) for r in results]
```

Then you can sum all counts to single value:

```
count = sum(counts)
```

Comment: I have to ask... learning all of this just takes lots and lots of time ? I cant seem to retain a lot of this for some reason.

Comment: @Oscalation, absolutely.  A lot of it comes down to time spent reading docs and experimenting with little snippets of code.  For myself, I find repetition is key to retention.  I don't really know an API until I've used it multiple times.  Otherwise, it's back to the docs and more play time in the REPL again.  Keep it up!  It does get easier over time.  :-)

Comment: Thank you Chris, I appreciate that.

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#finding-interesting-elements):

> Element.findall() finds only elements with a tag which are direct children of the current element.

These `count` elements are not the direct children of the root element.

You need to do something like

```
for i in tree.iter('count'):
    print i.text
```

If you want the sum of all `count`:

```
sum([int(i.text) for i in tree.iter('count')])  # returns 2482
```